# could not create constructor :: Kie Workbench

Tags: drools, complex-event-processing, kie, drools-fusion, kie-wb

I am using Kie workbench 6.3.0 to create rules. I am trying to run rule in stream mode.
I have created a project in kie-wb and created kie-base in it.
We are using kie server runtime for this.
This is the kmodule code generated:

```
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <kbase name="myKieBase" default="false" eventProcessingMode="stream" equalsBehavior="identity" packages="*"/>
</kmodule>
```

And following is the persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="com.sample:EventBusinessRules:2.6" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.sample.EventData</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

While deploying the project from Kie WB am getting the following error

```
Deployment of unit com.sample:SampleBusinessRules:2.7 failed: [Error: could not create constructor: null] [Near : {... new org.drools.persistence.jpa.mar ....}] ^ [Line: 1, Column: 5]
```

Please help me to resolve this error.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I removed the marshalling tag from kie-deployment-descriptor.xml and i didn't got any error while deploying project.

```
<marshalling-strategy>
                <resolver>mvel</resolver>
                <identifier>new org.drools.persistence.jpa.marshaller.JPAPlaceholderResolverStrategy("com.sample.rules:EventBusinessRules:2.6", classLoader)</identifier>
                <parameters/>
            </marshalling-strategy>
```

This tag is present under `<marshalling-strategies>`.
From Editor of kie-deployment-descriptor.xml remove the row added.

Comment: What's the impact of this change ?

Answer (score 0):

This persistence.xml file is for unit com.sample:EventBusinessRules:2.6.

```
<persistence-unit name="com.sample:EventBusinessRules:2.6" transaction-type="JTA">
```

The unit you try to deploy is com.sample:SampleBusinessRules:2.7. As a first step, I think you should try changing the name in xml.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Its my mistake i had changed the names of classes while posting it over here. I didnt changed it correctly everywhere. Persistence.xml file is generated automatically so there is no class name error. To solve this error i made a change in my kie-deployment-descriptor.xml file by removing the marshalling strategy tag.